# Is it better to place on CTA per plan or one for all plans?

Tags: call-to-action, pricing

We have four plans with a CTA: 'try it for free'

What is better:

1. Place one CTA per plan?
2. or place one CTA for all?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any difference in selecting the CTA of the 'M' as opposed to the 'XL' as far as this free trial goes? And is there a way to directly just purchase the XL version from this screen without trying the trial first?

Comment: Have you completed your user flows? I think if you worked through those first, you would be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion would be to use one CTA per item and here is why:

### One CTA per

My thought process:

1. Observe choices
2. I like plan "L"
3. A dedicated button, hoorah! :)
4. I bet if I press that button then the sign-up screen will not force me to choose again
5. Yay! the sign-up screen is clearly marked with what I want, and it even has a `<select>` box for me to switch my selection

### One CTA for all

My thought process:

1. Hmm, I want plan "L" but there is only one button
2. Am I gonna have to go through the entire sign-up process and choose what I want at the end?
3. Are they going to select the most expensive plan by default and make it un-intuitive to switch?
4. Will I have to jump through hoops to select the plan I want?

### Relevant examples

- http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/#hostingPlansTabs1
- http://asmallorange.com/hosting/

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to **go for the approach of showing four call to actions** for the users as the user can quickly scan through the plan offerings and choose the trial he wants to go through. This design would also enable  you to highlight  a trial plan for a specific model more specifically. Here are some examples of how sites use a similar approach

[image]

[image]

The challenge with just using a single call to action is that you are expecting the user to perform two actions i.e. scan through the offerings and select one and then choose to opt in for a free trial. This can help reduce your conversions since you are looking at a longer engagement and the user might not scan all the way to your call to action which is the main driving factor in conversion with the **"Free trial offer"** which informs users that this is just a trial and they are not being forced into making a payment right now.

To quote this [article from smashing magazine on call to action design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/13/call-to-action-buttons-examples-and-best-practices/)

> Often, a user’s hesitation to take action stems from thinking that an
>   action will be difficult, costly, or time consuming. By taking care of
>   these concerns, your call to action buttons can lead to more
>   conversions.
>
> For example, on Basecamp, the call to action button explicitly defines
>   the time it would take the user to sign up and tells users that
>   signing up is costless (free). This approach weakens two primary
>   users’ concerns when it comes to taking action online: paying (which
>   also requires them to take additional actions such as getting their
>   credit card) and time constraints.
>
> [image]